# How can I know from an Activity that all it's Fragments had onCreateView called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm loading data in the Activity that is displayed across all fragments.
The Activity sends them data via an "update" method the Fragments implement so they can populate the views.

Where can I safely call "update" from the Activity? (after all Fragments have finished "onCreateView")

Answer (score 2):

Your design is backwards. You should create `Fragments` in a way where once created, they can then call a method on your `Activity` in order to update the `View` content. According to the [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), `onCreateView` is called after `onAttach`, meaning you have access to your `Activity` via the `getActivity()` method. Additionally according to the documentation, you should have your `Activity` implement an interface in order to respond to a method called from a `Fragment`. For example, create the `interface` *OnFragmentCreatedListener*:

```
public interface OnFragmentCreatedListener {
    public void onFragmentCreated(Fragment fragment);
}
```

Then, implement this method in your `Activity` and add the following method:

```
public void onFragmentCreated(Fragment fragment) {
    //TODO handle view creation
}
```

Finally, in each of your `Fragment`s' `onCreateView` methods, add the following:

```
try {
    ((OnFragmentCreatedListener) getActivity()).onFragmentCreated(this);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Activity must inherit from interface OnFragmentCreatedListener", e);
}
```